# Linear operator: existence of inverse, equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

We have just introduced linear operators in my FA class. Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and $T:X \rightarrow Y$ a linear operator.

Claim: $T$ has a continuous inverse $T^{-1}$ on $T(X)$, if and only if there exists $c>0$ such that $$c \|x\|_X \le  \|Tx\|_Y, \text{ for all } x\in X.$$

I have the typical introductory lemma and theorems at my disposal.

Ideas: Under the assumption that such an inverse exists, I first noted that $T$ is surjective on $T(X)$, with the intention of utilizing that $T^{-1}$ would be linear, if $T$ was bijective. However, I couldn't conclude conclude anything about injectivity.

If I could show that $T$ was continuous, I'd know that for some $C\ge0$ holds $\|Tx\|_Y \le  C\|x\|_X$, which in turn I could maybe use to come somewhere near my claim. I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. I don't know if $T$ is continuous, which seems to be my biggest problem for now.

Am I missing something, which would allow me to conclude bijectivity of $T$, linearity of $T^{-1}$ or continuity of $T$? If not, what else is noteworth, which could be utilized to proove the claim?

Comment: Could you please explicitly state your question? Are you asking how to prove this claim?

Comment: Yes. I am asking how to prove the claim, and if my observations are valid clues which could help solving the proof.

Comment: Note that the definition of an inverse requires that $TT^{-1}$ and $T^{-1}T$ are both the identity map, which means that $T^{-1}$ and $T$ are necessarily bijective.

Comment: Actually, if I use this definition of an inverse, then one of the implications fail to hold. For instance, the map $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) \mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$ has no continuous two-sided inverse, but the map is in fact bounded away from zero, as is required

Comment: We cannot deduce from the information given that $T$ is continuous.  For example, if we take [$X$ to be $c_{00}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#c,_c0_and_c00), then the map $T:X \to X$ defined by
$$
T[(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}] = (nx_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}
$$
has a continuous inverse but fails to be continuous.

Comment: If we are given the existence of a continuous inverse, then
$$
c\|T^{-1}y\|_X \leq \|y\|_Y \ \text{for all } y \in T(X) \iff
c\|x\|_X \leq \|Tx\|_Y \ \text{for all } x \in X,
$$
so $T$ is indeed bounded away from zero. On the other hand, suppose that $T$ is bounded away from zero. Define the map $S:T(X) \to X$ by $S(T(x)) = x$.  We have
$$
c\|x\|_X \leq \|Tx\|_Y \ \text{for all } x \in X \iff
c\|Sy\|_X \leq \|y\|_Y \ \text{for all } y \in T(X),
$$
so $S$ is indeed bounded. It is not clear to me, however, that we can extend $S$ to a continuous map $\tilde S:Y \to X$.

Comment: Aren't we done here, since any bounded linear operator is continuous and we have shown that $S$ ist bounded?

Comment: I agree that the operator $S:T(X) \to X$ is bounded, but I would think that an "inverse" in this context would refer to a map from $Y$ to $X$. As I said before, it's not clear that $S$ can be extended to a bounded map $\tilde S:Y \to X$.

Comment: By the way, $T(X)$ refers to the image (range) of the operator $T$.

Comment: We know that () is a linear subspace of . Is the problem that there could be an element ̃ ∈∖() for which (̃ ) is undefined? In the problem it is specified that the inverse can only exist on $T(X)$.

Comment: Ah, that's an important detail of the problem that I missed. And to answer your question, the problem is that there might not be a way to define $S$ on every $y \in Y \setminus T(X)$ such that the resulting extension of $S$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are given the existence of a continuous inverse, then 
$$
c\|T^{-1}y\|_X \leq \|y\|_Y \ \text{for all } y \in T(X) \iff c\|x\|_X \leq \|Tx\|_Y \ \text{for all } x \in X,
$$
so $T$ is indeed bounded away from zero. On the other hand, suppose that $T$ is bounded away from zero. Define the map $S:T(X) \to X$ by $S(T(x)) = x$ so that $S$ is the inverse of $T$. We have 
$$
c\|x\|_X \leq \|Tx\|_Y \ \text{for all } x \in X \iff c\|Sy\|_X \leq \|y\|_Y \ \text{for all } y \in T(X),
$$
so the resulting map $S$ is bounded.

Comment: I didn't see the role of continuity of $T^{-1}$. Do we face any problem without the assumption? @BenGrossmann]

Comment: @falamiw If $T^{-1}$ is discontinuous, then there exists no $c>0$ such that $c\|T^{-1 }y\|_X \leq \|y\|_Y$. Equivalently, there is no $C$ such that $\|T^{-1}y\|_X \leq C\|y\|_Y$.

Comment: I know, $T$ is continuous at $x_0\in\mathcal{D}$ if for every $\epsilon<0$ there is a $\delta<0$ such that $\|x-x_0\|<\delta \implies \|Tx-Tx_0\|<\epsilon$ and $T$ is continuous if $T$ is continuous at every $x\in\mathcal D$. From here I could conclude $c\|T^{-1}y\|_X \leq \|y\|_Y @BenGrossmann. Sorry if the question is too simple as I start learning functional analysis recently.

Comment: @falamiw There is a statement that you will learn soon in your class if you haven't covered it already: a linear operator is continuous if and only if it is bounded.